# Double parentheses are being added to each NpgsqlParameter in my Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync call

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, parameters, npgsql

I am using Entity Framework. I need to make a sql query to add a column. This is what the relevant part of my code looks like:

```
string entityTableName = ClassGenerationStringUtilities.GetEntityTableName(newEntityName);
Type newPropType = newProp.PropertyType;
string sqlFieldName = ClassGenerationStringUtilities.AttributeParser(newPropName);
string postGreSqlType = DotNetToSqlMapping.GetPostGreType(newPropType);

object[] sqlParameters =
{
    new NpgsqlParameter("@tablename", entityTableName), 
    new NpgsqlParameter("@fieldname", sqlFieldName),
    new NpgsqlParameter("@postgretype", postGreSqlType),
};

await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("ALTER TABLE @tablename ADD @fieldname @postgretype", sqlParameters);
```

When I try to run it I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Then the InnerException tells me:

> {"ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near \"(\""}
>
> ErrorSql: ALTER TABLE (('car_entity')) ADD (('age')) (('int4'))

I have no idea why it's adding a double pair of parentheses for each parameter. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: As you can see, you cannot use parameters to represent table names or field names. I am not an expert of npgsql but this is a rule respected in every sql engine that I know of.

Comment: I thought the whole point is to use parameters to avoid injection attacks? I realized that I wasn't using the correct parameters for NpgsqlParameter(). It should have looked like this: new NpgsqlParameter(sqlFieldName, NpgsqlDbType.Varchar),
                        new NpgsqlParameter(postGreSqlType, NpgsqlDbType.Varchar), but I still get a problem with the ExecuteSqlCommandAsync because those parameters don't work. I was hoping I could avoid injection attacks by concatenating the input around double quotes "", but I got errors when I tested this in pg admin.

Comment: True, but Injection attacks come from untrusted sources of your values. Do you have your user free to input the names of the columns and tables?. If not then there is no concern of injection if you use string concatenations (this is probably the only exception to the rule) instead if your user types the names then you shoul add an extra layer of input checking. In any case I don't think you could use the parameters for this work neither in PGSQL